# How to disable request tracing in Google Cloud Trace?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-trace

I have a spring boot module which had been running on Google Cloud Run for more than an year now, which was enabled with Google Cloud Trace till date. I no longer want to collect the trace data and want to permanently disable the trace collection on that GCP environment. I tried to disable it by setting spring boot property `spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled: false` in the environment specific `application.yml` file and deployed it. But sadly, I do not see the changes getting reflected and the trace data is still getting collected on the cloud as shown below.

[image: Trace collection]

I am using below spring boot dependency for tracing and I do not want remove the same from my module's build configuration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Could someone let me know if I am doing something wrong here, or suggest me if I need to tweak any other property or configuration parameter in order to disable the traces?

Comment: We were enabling trace for few hours for a debug. We had part of code hidden in IF clause where ENV was checked. If ENV is not set do not send data to trace. I think in your case it might be problem with another property being used or the app is built with parameters forcing trace. If you are using docker, list all envs inside and check this and other properties.